# maximum order of an element in symmetric group

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

While doing my homework i find out that the maximum order of an element in $S_3$ is 3 (the element $(123)$) and the maximum order of an element in $S_4$ is 4 (the element $(1234)$)

Can i generalize that and say that the maximum order of an element in $S_n$ is n?

Comment: Check $S_5$ and see.

Comment: i asked to check if there is any theorem that prove what i wrote

Comment: What you wrote isn't true; you need only look at $S_5$ for a counterexample.

Comment: What vadim writes is accurate, @AviadChmelnik : before asking questions it is worthwhile to *really* try by yourself, for example by trying a decent ammount of examples. As he tells you,in $\;S_5\;$ you already have acounter example as the element $\;(12)(345)\;$ has order $\;6>5\$, and in $\;S_8\;$ you already have elements of order $\;15\;$ , say...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well after checking $S_5$ i saw that what i said is not correct:
element $(123)(45)$ has order of 6. thanks @vadim123

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221211/maximal-order-of-an-element-in-a-symmetric-group, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251333/orders-of-a-symmetric-group

Comment: You fell for the law of small numbers :)

Comment: @Hagen: LOL! This is how physicists (no offence!) prove that $60$ is divisible by any number: it is divisible by $1,2,3,4,5,6, ...$

Answer (score 2):

In general, you have to look at disjoint cycle types and hence for a "maximum" partition of $n=a_1 + \dots a_k$ and take the lcm of the $a_i$'s. Example for $S_7$: $7=2+5$ gives you order $10$ but $7=3+4$ yields $12$.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is [here](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2322839?searchUri=/action/doBasicSearch?Query=The%2bmaximum%2border%2bof%2ban%2belement%2bof%2ba%2bfinite%2bsymmetric%2bgroup&acc=off&wc=on&fc=off&Search=yes&searchText=The&searchText=maximum&searchText=order&searchText=of&searchText=an&searchText=element&searchText=of&searchText=a&searchText=finite&searchText=symmetric&searchText=group&uid=364965821&uid=2134&uid=2&uid=70&uid=3&uid=60&sid=21103196778387).

The maximum order of an element of finite symmetric group by William Miller, American mathematical monthly, page 497-506.

Comment: And already here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221211/maximal-order-of-an-element-in-a-symmetric-group.